# marking a radio button as checked jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code, why doesn't it work?

```
javascript:$('input[id=mod1radio]:eq(1)').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

and

```
<input id="mod1radio" type="radio" name="group1" value="24">
```

Comment: use `prop()` method not `attr()` if using jQuery version >=1.6 `prop('checked',true). See `attr()` docs

Answer (score 2):

Because `eq()` uses 0-based indexing (i.e. if you only have one of those, which you should since ids are distinct, you're selecting off the end of the array. `eq(0)` should work).

But if you have an id, why do that complicated select anyway? Why not just `$("#mod1radio")`?

also, as mentioned in the comments, `attr()` is deprecated, you should be using `prop()`

Answer (score 0):

There is only input. `eq(1)` would select the second one. @charlietfl suggests using `prop()` instead of `attr()` for jQuery >= version 1.6.

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. In addition, .attr() should not be used on plain objects, arrays, the window, or the document. To retrieve and change DOM properties, use the .prop() method.

Since the id `mod1radio` has to be unique, just use

```
$('#mod1radio').prop('checked', true);​
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mFkQQ/3/

If `mod1radio` should be a class instead, then use

```
$('.mod1radio:eq(0)').prop('checked', true);​
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mFkQQ/5/

Comment: I tried injecting javascript:$('#mod1radio').attr('checked', 'checked');​ but it wont work

Comment: Got it working now, problem was that I had a jquery mod that styled the radio buttons and therefore using this jquery didn't change the image that the mod used